# How do I click on this button on a web browser?

Tags: html, vb.net

How do I make the following click on a button using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="#" onclick="javascript:config_page_pns_call_list({id:'39110',monitored_prefix:'39',monitored_number_no_prefix:'3491906666',service_prefix:'39',service_number_no_prefix:'0694802015',status:'VALIDATED',insert_date:'2013-05-26 17:54:23',validate_date:'2013-05-26 17:55:55',active_until:'2112-05-26 17:54:23',active:'1',flat_sms_until:'null',flat_sms_active:'0',send_email:'1',send_sms:'0',send_all_sms:'null',recall:'0',record_call:'0'})"><i class="icon-list icon-white"></i> Elenco chiamate</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - Click Submit Button on Webbrowser page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210342/vb-net-click-submit-button-on-webbrowser-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("id:'31738'") Then
        Element.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For
    End If
Next Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to get the element and then:

```
elem.InvokeMember("onclick")
```

See [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Auto login form with Visual Basic*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194519/1967056) to see guidance on how to find your element.

If you need to get the JavaScript attribute to determine which is your element, get the "onclick" attribute [as specified in an answer to Stack Overflow question *'onclick' button not giving address using VB.NET*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048257/1967056):

```
elem.DomElement.attributes("onclick").value.ToString
```

So, to resume, you need to take all the tag elements with:

```
Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

And then loop and determine which one is the one you need to click.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but on html there is another code similar : <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="#" onclick="javascript:config_page_pns_call_list({id:'31738',monitored_prefix:'39',monitored_number_no_prefix:'3457752452',service_prefix:'39',service_number_no_prefix:'0694802015',status:'VALIDATED',insert_date:'2013-05-10 19:29:48',validate_date:'2013-05-10 19:34:37',active_until:'2112-05-10 19:29:48',active:'1',flat_sms_until:'null',flat_sms_active:'0',send_email:'1',send_sms:'0',send_all_sms:'null',recall:'0',record_call:'0'})"><i class="icon-list icon-white"></i> Elenco chiamate</a>

Comment: See [my answer in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17194519/1967056) to see a guidance on how to search for your element

Comment: sorry but i don't undestand..Into the page there is 2 code similar, different only for a number: 3491906666 and 3457752452.
The element is the same..